# Fetching JSON Data using angular

Tags: angularjs, json

Kindly help in fetching JSON Encoded data using Angular both array in single page.
please check with below JSON_Encoded data

```
[{"id":"25","rClientName":"Pravin Ingle","rContactNumber":"1234567890","rCompanyName":"Pro IT Technology","rEmail":"harshad.patil@proittechnology.com","rRequirement":"Requirement"}]

[{"id":"25","dSelectDomain":"DOmain","dDomainName":"DOmain","dRegisterDomainFrom":"DOmain","dStartDate":"DOmain","dEndDate":"DOmain","dRegistrationFor":"DOmain"}]
```

Thank you,
Harshad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try disposed into $scope.data, example :

```
 <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <ul ng-repeat="item in data">
    <li>{{item.rClientName}}</li> 
    <li>{{item.rContactNumber}}</li>
    <li>{{item.rCompanyName}}</li>
    <li>{{item.rEmail}}</li>
    <li>{{item.rRequirement}}</li>
  </ul>
</div>


$scope.data = [{"id":"25",
            "rClientName":"PravinIngle",
            "rContactNumber":"1234567890",
            "rCompanyName":"Pro IT Technology",
            "rEmail":"harshad.patil@proittechnology.com",
            "rRequirement":"Requirement"
          }]
```

for detail : 
http://jsfiddle.net/oxyjunkhead/bkUEu/3398/

Comment: Thank you for solution, but Okky there are 2 arrays... how can i fetch 2 arrys on single page.